# JavaでのFileReaderを用いて取得したデータを別クラスのListに格納したい

Tags: java

FileReadクラスで掃除役割というテキストファイルからデータを取得して、そのデータをYakuwariクラスでListに格納したいです。クラス間でのデータ移動方法を教えてほしいです。

```
public class FileRead {
    public static void yakuwariFileRead() {//役割読み込みメソッド
        Reader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader("掃除役割一覧.txt");//読み取り元データ
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //全て読み込み終わるまで
                //System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("「掃除役割一覧.txt」ファイルが見当たりません");

        } finally {
            if (fr != null) {
                try {
                    fr.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    System.out.print("ファイルが閉じられていません");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Yakuwari {
    public static void yakuwari() {
        List<String> yakuwariList = new ArrayList<String>();//役割一覧を格納するListの作成

        FileRead.yakuwariFileRead(); //掃除役割一覧を読み込むメソッド
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

元のプログラムを尊重すると、`yakuwariFileRead` メソッドに List を渡せるようにして、

```
public static void yakuwariFileRead(List<String> list) {//役割読み込みメソッド
    Reader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader("list.txt");//読み取り元データ
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //全て読み込み終わるまで
            list.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
```

Yakuwari 側で引数として渡してあげれば、一応は達成できますが……

```
FileRead.yakuwariFileRead(yakuwariList); //掃除役割一覧を読み込むメソッド

for (String line: yakuwariList) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

これでは、単に関数的なサブルーチンだと思うんですよね。クラス間での受け渡しと言えるのかどうか。

Comment: 引数でlistなどの配列を扱ったことがなかったので、想像してなかったです。ありがとうございます。今回はクラスでわけても、汎用的に使えるメソッドにすることができなかったため、Yakuwariクラスでメソッドを作成することにしました！